# Identity Platform authentication with Active Directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use GCP Identity Platform as an authentication system for my node.js project. The thing is, I need to sync the Google Cloud with my Active Directory On-Premise. How can I use the data synced from the Active Directory in Identity Platform?  If there is a better way to do this, please feel free to say it. I'm new to this technology.

I have been watching YouTube videos, but none of them solve my whole problem.

Thanks and have a good day.

Comment: Edit your post with more information. 1) How do you access Active Directory from Google Cloud? [link](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/10343242?sjid=15446678441895132912-NC) 2) What data do you need to sync? 3) What is an `owl problem`? 4) Both Active Directory and Identity Platform are complicated. What is your experience level? 5) Perhaps this [link](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/10616183?hl=en) for [link](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/106368?hl=en&ref_topic=2679497&sjid=15446678441895132912-NC) will help.

Comment: Sorry. I will provide you with more information: 1. I saw videos on YouTube using GCDS for Active Directory Sync, but I don't know any other method right now. 2. I want to sync username and password for authentication. 3. Sorry that was a typo, the right word was the whole problem. 4. None to zero. I am new on Google Cloud. 5. Thanks for the links, I will go there right now. Thanks for your time. My objective is to use Identity Platform as nodejs auth application. But I need to bring the usernames and password from a Active Directory. If you need more info, please tell me.

Comment: I have been working/developing with Active Directory since its release 30 years ago. You can spend your entire career learning that service. To start with you need to set up a VPN from your private data center to Google Cloud. Setting up site-to-site VPNs is another major skill. Once that is working you can use one of the Google services to sync from AD to Identity Platform. To sync passwords consider **Google Password Sync**. You will need help from your Active Directory and Network Security teams to configure everything. Start by meeting with them now as this will take months to setup.

Comment: Ok Thanks. But how I can handle the authentication from a node.js app using that username and password?. The app in node.js will run in Cloud Run.

Comment: Start by reading this [link](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/concepts-authentication).